# Differences between くださいますか/くださいませんか and いただけませんか/いただきたいのですが

Tags: word-choice, politeness

My textbook just put some examples without explanations, so i wonder if these sentences have the same meanings or there are differences.

> お名前をお書きくださいますか
> お名前をお書きくださいませんか。
>
> その論文の題をお教えいただけませんか
> その論文の題をお教えいただきたいのですが。

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48565/whats-the-difference-among-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-and-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14011/%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b-vs-%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b

Answer (score 1):

お名前をお書きくださいますか is a virtual order similar to …書いてください under a situation where the opponent is supposed to write it to begin with, or in theory a simple (or a tentative) inquiry if s/he (would) write it or not.

On the other hand, お名前をお書きくださいませんか is a request when the opponent doesn't necessarily have to do it.

その論文の題をお教えいただけませんか and その論文の題をお教えいただきたいのですが are a more modest request than お教えくださいませんか, and the latter is further a round-about way.

Answer (score 0):

1. お名前をお書きくださいますかand お名前をお書きくださいませんか are both polite and have same meaning.
2. They also have same meaning but if you say お教えいただきたいのですが,  some people might wait for your next words.. for example; その論文のお題を教えていただきたいのですが、可能ですか/お時間ありますか/ご存知ですか？